# Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3 in an MSI X99A SLI Plus

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility, computer-building, xeon

I have this Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3 that I took out of an old server, and I want to build a new multi function PC with it.

I searched around on the internet and I found this :
http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-MSI/X99A_SLI_PLUS.html

According to that link, the **E5-2670 v3** is compatible with **MSI X99A SLI Plus**. But before I go and buy that motherboard; I want, if possible, your confirmation about that.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> Before I go and buy that motherboard; I want, if possible, your
>   confirmation about that.

Yes;  The [Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/81709/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2670-v3-30M-Cache-2_30-GHz) is compatible with the [MSI X99A SLI Plus](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/X99A-SLI-PLUS.html#support-cpu)

Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3 Specifications:
[image]

MSI X99A SLI Plus Specifications:
[image]

Although the CPU in question is supported by the intial firmware for that motherboard ( 1.0 ).  You should still update the firmware to the current revision.  I determined that the intial firmware of the motherboard supports this CPU, by the fact the CPU compatability table references 7885v10.zip, as the revision that added the support.

*If you recieve a motherboard with that revision (or any revision except the current revision) of the firmware for that motherboard you want upgrade to the current version for system stability and memory compatibility reasons.*

The specific motherboard you asked about has been on the market for nearly 3 years.  We cannot predict which revision of the firmware the motherboard you will recieve.